# Matching a column from a table to another table

Tags: oracle-11g

I have 2 tables in a Oracle database and if I do:

```
SELECT ID,ID_EXTERN_FOR_JOB FROM SOL_PUBLIC.SOL_SUBSOL_CHESTIONARE@RACDB
WHERE ID=1207;
```

I get:

```
ID      ID_EXTERN_FOR_JOB
1207    -1
```

On the other table, if I do:

```
SELECT ID,ID_EXTERN_FOR_JOB FROM SOL.SOL_SUBSOL_CHESTIONARE
WHERE ID_EXTERN_FOR_JOB=1207;
```

I get

```
ID      ID_EXTERN_FOR_JOB
2009    1207
```

And I want to find out all the rows that don't match this "rule" of having the `ID_EXTERN_FOR_JOB` from `SOL` in `ID` FROM `SOL_PUBLIC` and I don't know how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT  PRIV.id_extern_for_job
,       PRIV.id
,       PUB.id_extern_for_job
FROM    SOL_PUBLIC.SOL_SUBSOL_CHESTIONARE@RACDB     PUB
,       SOL.SOL_SUBSOL_CHESTIONARE                  PRIV
WHERE   PRIV.id_extern_for_job = PUB.id
AND     PRIV.id <> PUB.id_extern_for_job;
```